# Hows does the particular value of $p$ determine the functions that are excluded from $L^p$ spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

What functions in general do the various $L^p$ spaces exclude? For example I've read that $f(x) = x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is not in $L^2(D)$ where $D = (0,1)$. So it seems that there is a direct relation between the inverse of the exponent and the $p$ value of the space?

Is it the case that in general $f(x) = x^{-\frac{1}{p}}$ is not in $L^p(D)$? Is that all there is to $L^p$ spaces or are there more complicated functions that are more difficult to classify as belonging to some $L^p$ space? Do the properties of the domain make a difference (dimension, closed, compact, etc...)?

Essentially what specific type of functions get excluded when we define a function $f$ and a value of $p$ such that $f \in L^p$? Some explicit examples (such as $f(x) = x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ would be particularly helpful to get some intuition on these spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you calculate it yourself:  For which exponent $a$ is $x^a$ square-integrable on $(0,1)$?  The same for $p$-integrable?

Other example:  For which $a,b$ is $x^a (\log x)^b$ in $L^p(0,1)$?

Examples on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ appear more contrived, since $x^a$ is not in that space for any $a$.  (You either have too big of a singularity or have too fat tails at infinity).

There are lots of answers on MSE about this already: [$L^p$-space inclusions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767352/lp-space-inclusions?rq=1)

Comment: Ok thanks, some useful information there. I do plan to make calculations myself but its good to get a general overview of the different factors affecting which functions get excluded, and also ideas of what calculations are worth experimenting with (such as your suggestion of "which $a, \ b$ is $x^a(\log x)^b$ in $L^p(0, 1)$".

Comment: Is there a systematic way for determining the $a, b$ for which $f(x) = x^a(\log x)^b$ is in $L^p(0, 1)$? I have tried several analytic attempts and it leads to very awkward integrals. So I then tried multiple attempts in Wolfram alpha and I can see that taking $a = b = -1/2$ gives that $f \in L^1(0, 1)$ but not in $L^2(0, 1)$. However if I take $a = b= -1/3$ then $f \in L^2(0,1)$. I can now see that each of the terms $x^a$ and $(\log x)^b$ become singular at either $0$ and $1$ and the value of $a$ and $b$ work to 'ease' the singularities at the endpoints.

Comment: But is there a systematic way to determine which $a$ and $b$ will mean that $f$ is in $L^p(0, 1)$ for some particular value of $p$? Randomly trying values in Wolfram alpha does not seem satisfactory!

Comment: Oops, it wasn't my intention to have two singularities.  Try $L^p(0,1/2)$ instead.  The behavior of $(\log x)^b$ near $x=1$ is redundant since it's just an algebraic singularity $(\log(1-x)\approx x$ when $x\approx 0$), which we're already considering at $x=0$.  Once you have $x^a$ solved you can add on the $\log x$ factor.  The point is $1/\log x < x^b$ for any $b>0$ (asymptotically around zero), basically you can add $\log x$ on and for the most part it won't affect anything (except possibly endpoint cases).  You could add $\log \log x$ in there too, that's even slower growing.

Comment: @eurocoder..do you linear integral equation for scattering theory