# Inclusions of $L^1[a,b]$, $L^2[a,b]$ and $L^3[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Define

$$L^p[a,b]=\{f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}\,\big| \int_a^b|f(x)|^p\text{d}x < \infty \}.$$

I want to show the followings

> $1$. If $g\in L^1[a,b]$ and $g\in L^2[a,b]$ then $g\in L^3[a,b]$.
>
> $2$. $L^2[a,b]\subset L^3[a,b].$
>
> $3$. Give an example of a function $g$ that $g\in L^3[a,b]$ and $g \notin L^2[a,b]$.

There is a hint which says if $p,q\ge1$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ then we have

$$\int_a^b |f(x)g(x)|\,\text{d}x\le 
\Big(\int_a^b |f(x)|^p\,\text{d}x\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}
\Big(\int_a^b |g(x)|^q\,\text{d}x\Big)^{\frac{1}{q}}.$$

> Does this inequality have a name? and where can I find a proof for it? (I don't know much about functional analysis so please refer me to a simple proof).

I used the inequality for $g(x)=1$ to obtain

$$\int_a^b |f(x)|\,\text{d}x\le 
\Big(\int_a^b |f(x)|^p\,\text{d}x\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}},$$

for an **arbitrary** $p\ge1$. This simply means that $L^p[a,b]\subset L^1[a,b]$. Specifically, we have

$$L^2[a,b]\subset L^1[a,b],\qquad L^3[a,b]\subset L^1[a,b].$$

So, $1$ and $2$ are indeed equivalent. If we replace $f(x)$ with $f^2(x)$ and $g(x)=1$ in the inequality we obtain

$$\int_a^b |f(x)|^2\,\text{d}x\le 
\Big(\int_a^b |f(x)|^{2p}\,\text{d}x\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}},$$

and choosing $p=\frac{3}{2}$ gives

$$\int_a^b |f(x)|^2\,\text{d}x\le 
\Big(\int_a^b |f(x)|^{3}\,\text{d}x\Big)^{\frac{2}{3}}.$$

However, this last inequality implies that $L^3[a,b]\subset L^2[a,b]$ which is the converse of what the question says! Am I missing something here?

Furthermore, $f(x)=x^{-\frac{5}{12}}$ is $L^2[0,1]$ but not $L^3[0,1]$. So, I guess there should be a typo in the question.

> Another example that I was thinking about was $f(x)=x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. It seems that it is $L^3[1,\infty)$ but not $L^2[1,\infty)$. Converse of the previouse example! Can you shed some light on this?

Future readers can take a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767352/lp-space-inclusions?rq=1) which is closely related.

Comment: you cannot stick with the integral of Riemann in a space of Lebesgue measurable functions. Moreover: it is not enough to show that $L^p\subset L^q$ to know that $L^p$ is embedded in $L^q$. The inequality $$\int_a^b |f(x)g(x)|\,\text{d}x\le 
\Big(\int_a^b |f(x)|^p\,\text{d}x\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}
\Big(\int_a^b |g(x)|^q\,\text{d}x\Big)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$ is named as Hölder's inequality

Comment: Well, it's true in general that $L^p\subseteq L^q$ for $p>q$ whenever your measure space is finite so you are, indeed, asked to prove something that isn't true.

Comment: @Masacroso: Well, I think I misused the term "Embedding". I just meant that what would be an inclusion relationship between these sets. :) Thanks for the name. :)

Comment: @WoolierThanThou: Thanks for the attention. :) Yeah, I got a similar conclusion at the end!

Comment: @WoolierThanThou: What does it mean for a measure space being finite in simple terms? :)

Comment: The interval $[a,b]$ has finite length, as opposed to, say, $[0,\infty)$ or $\mathbb{N}$ (which has infinitely many points which should naturally all have mass one). For instance, over $\mathbb{N}$, the reverse inclusions hold: So $L^p(\mathbb{N})\subseteq L^q(\mathbb{N})$ whenever $p<q$. No inclusion relations at all hold over $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou well, $\Bbb N $ have zero Lebesgue measure, so indeed $L^p(\Bbb N )=L^q(\Bbb N )$ for any chosen $p,q\in[0,\infty ]$ :). Maybe you mean the $\ell ^p$ spaces with the counting measure.

Comment: Functions that are Riemann integrable are in every $L^p$ because they are bounded.

Comment: @Mascroso: I don't think there's any standard to what $L^p(\mathbb{N})$ should mean, so I just omitted the measure (the thing I wrote in parenthesis definitely implies that I'm talking about the counting measure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to the comments, the inequality is called **H$\ddot{\mathbf{\text{o}}}$lder** inequality. The correct inclusion relation is

$$L^3[a,b]\subset L^2[a,b]\subset L^1[a,b].$$

More generally, if $p<q$ and $[a,b]$ is bounded then

$$L^q[a,b]\subset L^p[a,b].$$

For unbounded domains, this may not be true as the example at the end of question points out. This also implies that the H$\ddot{\text{o}}$lder inequality is not valid for such domains.