# Inclusion of $L^p$-spaces in Infinite measure set

Tags: real-analysis

I know that if $\Omega$ is a set of finite measure for $1\le p\le\infty$ then $L^\infty\subseteq.....\subseteq L^p......\subseteq L^1$.

But if $\mu(\Omega)=\infty$ $L^P \not\subseteq L^q$ or$L^q \not\subseteq L^p$  ?

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767352/lp-space-inclusions?rq=1 answer your question?

Comment: If $\mu (A)=\infty$ for every non-empty measuarble set $A$ then $L^{p}=L^{q}=\{0\}$.